# Tensorflow keras model throwing error for categorical classificiation

Tags: numpy, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a 2d numpy array (49000 entries with 784 feature columns) with training data and corresponding label array (y_train) which consists of categorical values labelled from 1 to 10.

Numpy array details -

```
print(X_train.shape, "X_train.shape")
print(y_train.shape, "y_train.shape")
print(X_val.shape, "X_val.shape")
print(y_val.shape, "y_val.shape")
print(np.unique(y_train))

Output - 
(49000, 784) X_train.shape
(49000,) y_train.shape
(1000, 784) X_val.shape
(1000,) y_val.shape
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

This is the code I am running -

```
y_train_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
y_val_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=10)
y_test_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train_one_hot )).batch(32)
dataset_validate = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val_one_hot )).batch(32)
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test_one_hot )).batch(32)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()],
)

model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=10, validation_data=dataset_validate)
```

I get the following output

```
 Epoch 1/10
1532/1532 [==============================] - 16s 10ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0294 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
1532/1532 [==============================] - 12s 8ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
1532/1532 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
1532/1532 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
1532/1532 [==============================] - 13s 9ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Can anyone say what the problem is in my code? Please note that the y array has categorical labels  so this is NOT a regression model.

Comment: Please do not edit the question in this manner. Further viewers of your question will not get anything meaningful from your edit. If you want to mention the resolved issue accept the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using labels as integer (e.g. 0,1,2,..9) shape `(batch_size, 1)` and output size of your model is `(batch_size,10)` i.e. probability of each class.
Either you change your labels in `one_hot` which will change your single label in a vector of size `[num_classes]`. Syntax in given below.

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(
    y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32'
)
```

(in your case `num_classes=10`)

or use `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` which requires integer labels as mentioned by @AloneTogether. Syntax as follows.

```
tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False, reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)
```

Comment: I have updated my post, I made the changes as suggested by one hot enconding the variable. I get really weird values in out put for accuracy and loss.